# Binding model with child list MVC 3 razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following model :

```
    public class ContratoDetailsViewModel
    {
        [StringLength(50)]
        [RegularExpression("^[a-z0-9_\\+-]+(\\.[a-z0-9_\\+-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9-]+)*\\.([a-z]{2,4})$")]
        [DisplayName("E-Mail Adm.")]
        public string emailAdm { get; set; }
    }


    public class ContratoDetailContainerViewModel
    {
        public ContratoDetailsViewModel contrato { get; set; }
        public IList<ContratoModels.CCasinoViewModel> ccasinos { get; set; }
    }

    public class CCasinoViewModel
    {
        public short codigo { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> listCasinos { get; set; }
    }
```

the following view :

```
@model ContratoModels.ContratoDetailContainerViewModel
@{
    ...
}
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { currentaction = ViewBag.mode }))
{
...
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.contrato.emailAdm, state1)<br />
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ccasinos,"test")
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

in the folder "EditorTemplates" i have a template called "test.cshtml" :

```
@model List<ContratoModels.CCasinoViewModel>
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m[i].codigo,Model[i].listCasinos)
}
```

My Controller post action is like this :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Details(ContratoModels.ContratoDetailContainerViewModel model, FormCollection form)
    {
           var contrato = model.contrato;
           var casinos = model.ccasinos;
    }
```

Before send the view ccasinos,codigo and listCasinos are initialised
when i am in debug mode i see the value of them... the form display work like a charm.
BUT ... when i submit the form the model.ccasinos is always null !! why ?
thank you very much for your reply.

note : I use a EditorFor with the child of my main model but if there is a better solution
for display and submit with MCV 3 I am interested ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ccasinos, "test")
```

with this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ccasinos)
```

and then rename your `test.cshtml` template to `CCasinoViewModel.cshtml` and replace its contents with this:

```
@model CCasinoViewModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.codigo, Model.listCasinos)
```

Because the editor template is now named the same way as the type of the list, ASP.NET MVC will automatically render it for each element of this list so that you don't have to write loops.

Also you can safely remove the `FormCollection` argument from your action. It's completely useless when you are working with view models:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Details(ContratoModels.ContratoDetailContainerViewModel model)
{
    var contrato = model.contrato;
    var casinos = model.ccasinos;
    ...
}
```

Comment: thank darin ! it's working ! but the problem now if i want delete a line in Ajax i must send again all the model ... what is the solution for use for example a partial view for render only the list of CCasinoViewModel integrated in ContratoDetailContainerViewModel  ?